# BuddyPress notification generated from Gravity Form submission

Tags: wordpress, buddypress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a website running both gravity forms and buddypress where a gravity form takes information which is sent to the post authors' email. I'd like to also send the contents of the submitted form to the authors messages in buddy press.

Is this possible? How do I configure gravity to send a notification to buddypress as well as the one it sends now?

Comment: What information is this form accepting?

Comment: A name, phone number, email and text area (300 characters max). Essentially all text.

Comment: So is this form creating a post? Is the person filling it out a user on your site, and if so, are they logged in?

Comment: Yes, the form requires a registered and logged in user to send the form.

Comment: So, you have a logged in user who's filling out a form and you want to email their submission to them *and* send it to their private messages?

Comment: correct. I have figured the email part out through Gravity Forms notifications. It's the private message part that I don't know how to do.